# How to validate input data using ajax in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-5.6

**testAjax function** *inside* **PostsController class**:

```
public function testAjax(Request $request)
  {
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['name' => 'required']);

    if ($validator->fails()){
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        echo $errors;
    }
    else{
      echo "welcome ". $name;
    }

  }
```

inside **web.php** file:

```
Route::get('/home' , function(){
  return view('ajaxForm');
});

Route::post('/verifydata', 'PostsController@testAjax');
```

**ajaxForm.blade.php:**

```
<script src="{{ asset('public/js/jquery.js') }}"></script>

  <input type="hidden" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  Name<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <input type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submit").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var token = $("#token").val();
        /**Ajax code**/
        $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url:"{{URL::to('/verifydata')}}",
        data:{name:name,  _token: token},
        success:function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);
            }
          });
          /**Ajax code ends**/    
      });
  });
</script>
```

So when click on submit button by entering some data then the output message(*echo "welcome ". $name;*) is printing. But when I click on submit button with empty text box then it does not print the error message from the controller and it throws a 422 (Unprocessable Entity) error in console. Why my approach is wrong here and how can I print the error message then. Please help. Thank you in advance.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Send json data from laravel and read from ajax response

Comment: Laravel already sends a good error response all you need to do is handle errors in the client-side

Comment: I would suggest you use axios and Vue.js to do it. very easy. You can send the data the laravel, and in the controller, you make `if(request()->wantsJson())` and you return the data. then in the frontend, you catch it. and display on the screen. it may seem hard, but it is really 1 minute of work.

Answer (score 27):

Your approach is actually not wrong, it's just, you need to catch the error response on your ajax request. Whereas, when Laravel validation fails, it throws an `Error 422 (Unprocessable Entity)` with corresponding error messages.

```
/**Ajax code**/
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "{{ url('/verifydata') }}",
    data: {name: name,  _token: token},
    dataType: 'json',              // let's set the expected response format
    success: function(data){
         //console.log(data);
         $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data.message);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        if (err.status == 422) { // when status code is 422, it's a validation issue
            console.log(err.responseJSON);
            $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(err.responseJSON.message);
            
            // you can loop through the errors object and show it to the user
            console.warn(err.responseJSON.errors);
            // display errors on each form field
            $.each(err.responseJSON.errors, function (i, error) {
                var el = $(document).find('[name="'+i+'"]');
                el.after($('<span style="color: red;">'+error[0]+'</span>'));
            });
        }
    }
});
/**Ajax code ends**/
```

On your controller

```
public function testAjax(Request $request)
{
    // this will automatically return a 422 error response when request is invalid
    $this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required']);

    // below is executed when request is valid
    $name = $request->name;

    return response()->json([
         'message' => "Welcome $name"
    ]);

  }
```

Comment: This is great. The only thing I don't like is that the error is shown multiple times when the error persists and the user presses the submit button again.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a better approach to validation:

In your controller:

```
public function testAjax(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, [ 'name' => 'required' ]);
   return response("welcome ". $request->input('name'));
}
```

The framework then will create a validator for you and validate the request. It will throw a [`ValidationException`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php) if it fails validation.

Assuming you have not overriden how the validation exception is rendered here's the default code [the built-in exception handler](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L213) will run

```
protected function convertValidationExceptionToResponse(ValidationException $e, $request)
{
        if ($e->response) {
            return $e->response;
        }
        $errors = $e->validator->errors()->getMessages();
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json($errors, 422);
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->input())->withErrors($errors);
}
```

Again this is handled for you by the framework.

On the client side you should be able to do:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submit").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var token = $("#token").val();
        /**Ajax code**/
        $.ajax({
           type: "post",
           url:"{{URL::to('/verifydata')}}",
           data:{name:name,  _token: token},
           success:function(data){
              //console.log(data);
              $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);
           },
           error: function (xhr) {
               if (xhr.status == 422) {
                   var errors = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                   if (errors.name) {
                       alert('Name is required'); // and so on
                   }
               }
           }
        });
          /**Ajax code ends**/    
      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

best way for handle in php controller :

```
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'footballername' => 'required',
        'club' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
    ]);
    
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Record is successfully added']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code for form validation in Vannilla Javascript

```
const form_data = new FormData(document.querySelector('#form_data'));
fetch("{{route('url')}}", {
       'method': 'post',
       body: form_data,
 }).then(async response => {
      if (response.ok) {
         window.location.reload();
      }
      const errors = await response.json();
      var html = '<ul>';
      for (let [key, error] of Object.entries(errors)) {
          for (e in error) {
              html += `<li>${error[e]}</li>`;
          }
      }
      html += '</ul>';
      //append html to some div

      throw new Error("error");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     console.log(error)
  });
```

Controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;//Use at top of the page
$rules = [
    'file' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:1024',
    'field1' => 'required',
    'field2' => 'required'
   ];
$validator = Validator::make($request->post(), $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
   return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
}
session()->flash('flash', ['status' => 'status', 'message' => 'message']);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery Code:**

```
  let first_name=     $('.first_name').val();
            let last_name=      $('.last_name').val();
            let email=     $('.email').val();
            let subject=      $('.subject').val();
            let message=        $('.message').val();

    $('.show-message').empty();

    console.log('clicked');
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : '{{route("contact-submit")}}',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data: {
            first_name,
            last_name,
            email,
            subject,
            message,
        },
        success: function(data) {

            console.log('data',data);
            $('.show-message').html('Form Submitted');
        },

        error :  function(data,data2,data3)
        {

            let response=data.responseJSON;
            let all_errors=response.errors;

            console.log('all_errors',all_errors);

            $.each(all_errors,function(key,value){
                $('.show-message').append(`<p>${value}</p>`);
            });


        }
    });
```

**Controller Code:**

```
$validator=Validator::make($request->all(),[
                'first_name'=>'required',
                'last_name'=>'required',
                'email'=>'required|email',
                'subject'=>'required',
                'message'=>'required',
            ]);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'success'=>false,
                'errors'=>($validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()),
            ],400);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success'=>true,
        ],200);
```

See More Details at: https://impulsivecode.com/validate-input-data-using-ajax-in-laravel/